# Union of two intervals excluding a number

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We had this assignment at school:

> What is the union of $[-3,4]$ and $(3,5]$, i.e. what is $$[-3,4] \cup (3,5]$$

Our teacher say the result is $[-3,5]$ \ $\{3\}$
I do not agree. I think it is $[-3,5]$.
Could you tell me who is right and why? See a sketch below:

[image: Assignment]

Comment: Your notation is non standard. Also, it is a bit unreasonable to expect others to edit your question because you are on the phone. Just get off the phone.

Comment: Is $<3, 5] = (3, 5]$? And what is $[-3, 5]\{3\}$?!

Comment: You need to explain your notation. It is non standard.

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić You have been part of the SE network for a long time and should know how things work. I agree that new users should get a little break, but experienced users should know better. To answer your question: you are correct that $[-3,3]\cup(3,5] = [-3,5]$. However your teacher is right if the first interval is open at the right end, i.e. $[-3,3)\cup(3,5] = [-3,5]~$\ $\{3\}$.

Comment: Thank you @Winther that is what i thought. And sorry for doing the question like this, but I only had 5 minutes to write this. And I did not know the notation wasnt standard. It is how we do it in Croatia. And no I did not just take an image of the teachers drawing. I actually drew it myself.

Comment: @RobertoNicbaAnićBanić I had a little go editing your question, see if I messed something up. btw in your sketch it seems the first interval is $[-3,4]$ instead of $[-3,3]$.

Comment: Yes it is. I will fix it

Comment: If you drew the drawing, you should show it to your teacher to ensure that it is the intended problem.  If you and your teacher have different conceptions of the problem, you could be disagreeing merely on semantics and not on mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. To prove this we start with the definition of a union of two sets:

$$A\cup B \equiv \{x ~~: ~~x\in A ~~\lor ~~x\in B \}$$

or in words: an element $x$ is in $A\cup B$ if $x$ is contained in $A$ or in $B$ (or both).

For your case $A=[-3,4]$ and $B=(3,5]$. Every number $x\in [-3,3]$ is in $A$, every number $x\in (3,4]$ is in both $A$ and $B$ and  every number $x\in(4,5]$ is in $B$. Further we see that if $x<-3$ or $x>5$ then $x$ is in neither set so it follows that

$$A\cup B = [-3,5]$$

Note that the point you and your teacher disagree about ($3$) is contained in $A$ so by the definition above it must be in $A\cup B$.